# Hudson and JTReg tests

Tags: continuous-integration, hudson

I am using Hudson to continuously integrate a project using JTReg testing framework.  As far as I know, `jtreg` doesn't output JUnit-style XML reports.  Is there a way to publish `jtreg` tests into Hudson reporting?

I saw an IcedTea blog post about integrating Hudson with a slightly-modified version of `jtreg`, but I cannot find that version.

Has anyone built a converter tool that, given `jtreg` reports, will generate JUnit reports?

Answer (score 1):

There is a small script I'm using to create junit xml result files from jtreg results generated during openjdk's build process. It is a bit hackish, but seems to work...

jtreg2junit.sh:

https://gist.github.com/2581071

Comment: Please see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers

Answer (score 1):

You can use a newer version of jtreg (vailable on the openjdk website) to produce junit-happy xml files, as follows

```
jtreg -jdk:...  -xml .....
```

or
    jtreg -jdk:...  -xml:verify ...

This will generate FooBar.jtr.xml ie. the the jtr in xml format, which can be loaded and interpreted by a hudson/jenkins system as junit test. The latter option verifies the output using the SAXParser pin-point any issues that the xml file might have, running this slows down jtreg, but this is better than chasing obscure hudson/jenkins errors.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [xUnit plugin](http://wiki.hudson-ci.org/display/HUDSON/xUnit+Plugin).  It is designed to read in test results from any unit test framework.

Comment: Thanks!  Unfortunately, it doesn't claim to support jtreg!

Comment: Yes, the whole point of the xunit plugin is that you can write a simple XSL conversion for any XML file format - including jtreg.